# Matcher for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, testing, numpy, pandas

I am looking for an solid example of a matcher for pandas DataFrame. I am surprised that I have not been able to find anything suitable yet.

My matcher has the following requirements :

1. Compare if two data frames are the same, give the option to ignore column order and give an acceptable level of tolerance (rounding)
2. Describe the mismatch that occurs standard DataFrame matcher

I have checked out [assert_frame_equal](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/29de89c1d961bea7aa030422b56b061c09255b96/pandas/util/testing.py#L621) from pandas.util.testing and found [this](http://penandpants.com/2014/10/07/testing-with-numpy-and-pandas) blog post pretty helpful but the custom matcher still fell short and has a bug in it around comparing DataFrames with different indexes

Comment: You might want to post small sample datasets and the actual matching code from the blog to make this more specific.  As asked this is too general to get a good answer here (and I'm surprised this isn't getting downvoted yet to be honest).

Comment: Why would two dataframes with different indexes be the same?

Comment: They definitely shouldn't @MarkGraph

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt is as follows

```
def assert_frames_equal(actual, expected, use_close=True, max_delta=1e-06, ordered=True):
    if ordered == False:
        actual = actual.sort(axis=1)
        expected = expected.sort(axis=1)

    mismatch = None

# 1. Check both objects are data frames
    if  not isinstance(actual, pd.DataFrame) or not isinstance(expected, pd.DataFrame):
        return False

# 2. Check both data frames have the same indexes in the same order        
    if not np.array_equal(actual.index.values, expected.index.values):
        return False 

# # 4. Check that both data frames have the same columns, possibly in the same order
    if list(actual.columns.values) != list(expected.columns.values):
        return False 

# split out non numeric and numeric rows
    obj_cols_expected = expected.columns[expected.dtypes == object]
    num_cols_expected = expected.columns[expected.dtypes != object] 

    obj_cols_actual = actual.columns[actual.dtypes == object]
    num_cols_actual = actual.columns[actual.dtypes != object] 


# check that data frames have the same values, possibly within an tolerence
    obj_columns_same = (expected[obj_cols_expected].fillna('') == actual[obj_cols_actual].fillna('')).all().all()
    if use_close :
        num_columns_same = np.allclose(actual[num_cols_actual].fillna(0), expected[num_cols_expected].fillna(0), max_delta)
    else:
        num_columns_same = (actual[num_cols_actual].fillna(0) == expected[num_cols_expected].fillna(0)).all().all()
    return obj_columns_same & num_columns_same
```

Comment: Could you please describe what you're doing with the code? Sometimes the idea is more interesting than the code itself.